# Random value for Z axis

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, axis

I want to know how in this set-up I can randomize object size by Z-axis and leave this stacket?

[image: 1]
[image]

Comment: Editors! There is no rotation in the original post. I know the post is hard to understand, so maybe is better to ask author to clarify what he means?

Comment: Do you want blocks to have the same size in x and y-axis, while keeping z-axis untouched?

Comment: @Crantisz yes. exactly! to make this effect https://www.instagram.com/p/CeftS76NgDF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Ignore the below passage. Add a random value node, set it to vector and set the top two min and max values to 0. Connect this to the size of your cube instance node.

You could add a random value node, set it to *Vector*, and make the min and max values of the top 2 values to 0 or anything that suits you (must be the same). Now the last value on it out of the three is the Z-Axis. Increase the max value for it to have a random Z-Acis scale. Connect it to the scale input of the instances on points node.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean, to replace the current random value node or add one more to this one?

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk just do it on the original one.

Comment: not sure, if I'm making this right, but it doesn't work( https://tppr.me/iUf6G

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk Oh sorry please undo it! I didn't notice the scale input was there for the accumulate position too. Add another random value node for the scale as I said.

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk It will work if you add a new random value node instead of replacing the original one

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But it's still doesn't work( https://tppr.me/eFEM
I just need to scale Z-axis and stack object close to each other, Like on this artwork https://www.instagram.com/p/CeftS76NgDF/

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk Check my new edits, should work

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk the last solution also worked fine, you just had to set the top two values of the random value node max to 0.

Comment: @EugeneNechiporchuk That's what you were doing wrong all the time, though at least you found your solution :)

Comment: thank you so much! ☺️

Comment: No problem, good to see you found the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Combine XYZ** node to get vector out from 2 static and one dynamic value:

[image]

Comment: Oh! thank you so much! so a simple way!!